# Approximation of bounded $C^2$ functions with complex exponentials

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, approximation, covariance

I was studying on the book Random Fields and Geometry (R.J Adler, J.E. Taylor) when I came up with this probability lemma:

> Let $X,Y$ be two independent, standard (with mean$=0$ and variance=$Id_k$), $k$-dimensional Gaussian vectors and $f,g:\mathbb{R}^k\to \mathbb{R}$ two $C^2$ bounded functions.
>   Then: 
>   $$ Cov(f(X),g(X))=\int_0^1\mathbb{E}\left[\nabla f(X)\cdot \nabla g\left(\alpha X+\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}Y\right)\right]d \alpha.$$

The proof is really straightforward for $f(x)=e^{it\cdot x}$ and $g(x)=e^{is\cdot x}$ for $t,s,x\in\mathbb{R}^k.$

Then, the authors state that well-known approximation results help in order to conclude.

My question now is: **which approximation results are used to generalize the result to general $C^2$ functions?** I couldn’t find any Fourier analysis result that would help me.

Thanks to everybody.

Comment: Is it maybe $f(X),g(Y)$ on the left instead? I haven't tried, but those two special choices of $f,g$ suggest to me Fourier analysis

Comment: @CalvinKhor no no, it has twice $X$.

Comment: Fourier transform, basically. But I don't think the result is true if you don't place further restrictions on the behavior of the derivative at infinity

Comment: Ah wait, if by $C^2$ bounded you mean "finite $C^2$ norm" then you should be fine

Comment: I think that bounded is meant in the $C^0$ sense, sadly. During these days I thought that the fact that they are gaussian can help us assuming that the functions are compactly supported, apart from a low-probability set....